# Suspected error in proof about partitioned matrices in Matrix analysis by Roger Horn

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, block-matrices

I'm quite confused when reading Horn and Johnson's *Matrix analysis* (second edition) p.20 , 0.7.6 Rank in a partitioned matrix and rank-principal matrices .

Denote $M_{m,n}(F)$ as the set of all $m\times n $ matrices over field $F$ (arbitrary) , for square matrices  use abbreviation .  Partition $A \in M_n(F)$ as
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{array}\right)
,\quad A_{11} \in M_r(F) , A_{22} \in M_{n-r}(F)
$$
The book attempts to prove (actually it's $\iff$ but I don't think it's relevant here)

> $rk(A)=rk[A_{11}\;A_{12} ] = rk\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}\\ A_{21}\end{bmatrix} \implies A_{11}$ is nonsingular .

as follow

> Suppose $A_{11}$ is singular , then $rk(A_{11})=k<r $ . There are nonsingular $S,T\in M_r(F)$ such that
> $$
> SA_{11}T = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
> I_{k} & 0 \\
> 0 & 0_{r-k}
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
> Therefore,
> $$
> \hat{A} =
> \left(\begin{array}{rr}
> S & 0 \\
> 0 & I_{n-r}
> \end{array}\right) A 
> \left(\begin{array}{rr}
> T & 0 \\
> 0 & I_{n-r}
> \end{array}\right)
>  = 
>  \left(\begin{array}{rr}
> SA_{11}T & SA_{12} \\
> A_{21}T & A_{22} 
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
> has rank $r$ , as do its block row and column . Because the $r^{th}$ row of the first block column of $\hat{A} $ is zero , there must be some column in $SA_{12}$ whose $r^{th}$ entry is not zero, which means that $\hat{A} $ has at least $r + 1$ independent columns. This contradicts $rank \hat{A} = rank A = r$ ,so $A_{11}$ must be nonsingular.
> $\square$

**Question :** Why $rank \hat{A} = rank A = r ? $  I only know $rank \hat{A} = rank A$ since multiplication with nonsingular matrices won't change rank . I don't recall making any assumption on $A_{12}\in M_{r,n-r}(F),A_{21}\in M_{n-r,r}(F)$ and $A_{22}$ , so let all of them be $0$ , then $rk(\hat{A}) = k < r $ .

Nonetheless , if assume $rank \hat{A} = rank A = r $ , then the rest of the proof follows . I couldn't find such assumption .  Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, "$=r$" should be added to the equal-ranks assumption. Good catch! Tell Roger Horn at rhorn@math.utah.edu .

Comment: The proposition is false without “$=r$” in the equal-ranks assumption. Consider the zero matrix for instance.

Comment: By the way, I think the proof in the book is overly complicated. Here I believe is a simpler one. Since $\operatorname{rank} A=\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{A_{11}&A_{12}}$, the rows in the second block row of $A$ are linear combinations of those in the first block row. Therefore $A_{21}=YA_{11}$ for some matrix $Y$. Now $A_{11}$ is nonsingular because
$$
r=\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{A_{11}\\ A_{21}}
=\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{A_{11}\\ YA_{11}}
=\operatorname{rank}A_{11}.
$$